# gob-decoding into an interface using UnmarshalBinary

Tags: go

I am trying to read a gob-encoded Go object into a variable of interface type.  When I let `gob` to the encoding itself, my code works (see below).  In contrast, when I try to encode/decode the object manually, using `MarshalBinary` and `UnmarshalBinary`, my program crashes with the following message:

```
panic: interface conversion: interface is nil, not encoding.BinaryUnmarshaler [recovered]
    panic: interface conversion: interface is nil, not encoding.BinaryUnmarshaler
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Details.** The interface I am using is given by

```
type Duck interface {
    encoding.BinaryMarshaler
    encoding.BinaryUnmarshaler
    Quack()
}
```

The actual object I am encoding and trying to decode is

```
type A struct {
    x byte
}

func (a *A) MarshalBinary() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte{a.x}, nil
}

func (a *A) UnmarshalBinary(data []byte) error {
    a.x = data[0]
    return nil
}

func (a *A) Quack() {
    fmt.Println(a.x)
}
```

I have registered the type with gob using

```
gob.Register(&A{})
```

and encoding objects of type `&A` seems to work fine.  I try to gob-decode the object into an interface variable using the commands

```
dec := gob.NewDecoder(buf)
var duck2 Duck
dec.Decode(&duck2)
```

The last of these commands results in the panic shown above.

Full code is on [play.golang.org](https://play.golang.org/p/-zS7QjEJg9x).

**Updated.** Without the custom en-/decoder, the code works (after renaming `a.x` to `a.X`, to make the field globally visible): https://play.golang.org/p/y8nWNhObUwb

Comment: You don't want to marshal or unmarshal the interface, you want to marshal and unmarshal the struct.  https://play.golang.org/p/_QdYcjV9GTo

Comment: @sberry I want to read the result into an interface variable, without having to know in advance which concrete type I'm receiving (the actual interface has several possible implementations, and gob data comes in over a network connection).  So, while your code avoids the panic, it does not solve my problem.

Comment: Does it work without your customer marshaling / unmarshaling (will need to export the X field then)

Comment: @sberry Yes, it does!  See https://play.golang.org/p/y8nWNhObUwb .  I've added this link to my question, to make it easier to find.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/m6s88GzQDE0

Comment: @beiping96 yes, I had thought about this.  Initialising the interface object makes the "interface is nil" error go away.  But for this to work I need to know the concrete type in advance (which I don't).

Comment: Seems to be caused by the same problem as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43324919/gob-panics-decoding-an-interface
The interface's `UnmarshalBinary` implementation takes, unfortunately, precedence over gob's handling of registered interface implementations. So gob doesn't even transfer type information.