# Is there any point in embedding `json.Unmarshaller` or `encoding.BinaryUnmarshaller` into an interface X, besides ensuring X implements them?

Tags: go, gob

I have interface like below:

```golang
type Car interface {
    json.Marshaler
    json.Unmarshaler
}
```

and a struct that implements above interface:

```
var _ Car = (*Honda)(nil)
```

**The benefit of embedding a json marshaler into the interface is that I can call `MarshalJSON` method directly on a variable of the type `Car`.**

I don't understand what would be the point of embedding an unmarshaler, though, because at compile time the compiler doesn't know the concrete type implementing the interface.

So, is there any point in embedding a json.Unmarshaller into `Car`, besides making sure `Honda` implements them?

Answer (score 2):

Interface embedding is simply interface composition. The resulting interface will have all the methods of the embedded interfaces. Writing:

```
type Car interface {
    json.Marshaler
    json.Unmarshaler
}
```

is equivalent to writing:

```
type Car interface {
    UnmarshalJSON([]byte,any) error
    MarshalJSON(any) ([]byte,error)
}
```

One benefit of such embedding is that whoever reads the `Car` interface can see that it has to support json marshal/unmarshaling using the stdlib conventions, which can be difficult to spot if the interface get large.

Comment: Makes sense. I value the readability aspect, but I was wondering whether there are any other implications or potential uses. The readability value gets in my way specifically with binary marshaler/unmarshaler embedding and gob a la. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57485698/gob-decoding-into-an-interface-using-unmarshalbinary

Comment: I am not aware of a runtime mechanism that can distinguish if an interface method is embedded, or declared directly in the interface. An interface is simply a set of methods.